# Converting Byte Array's into multiple object types

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to write multiple objects into a bytearray then when I read them I can use them as needed.

Here's the out code:

```
ByteArrayDataOutput out = ByteStreams.newDataOutput();
out.writeUTF(string + ", " + int + ", "+ a_file);
```

Now when this is received I kind of want to read the data as a string tokenizer (I know it wouldn't be a string tokenizer). So when I read it how do I know what is the string, what is the file, and what data is the int?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is serialization and deserialization for this very purpose. Your objects you want to write must implement the Serializable interface. Generate serialUID after every object change, if you gonna serialize your custom objects too. Serialized form can be understood as byte array of course.